# Can a 2000 Elo rated player teach me middlegame play properly?

Tags: theory, positional-play, training, elo, coach

[I have reached 2500 in the chess.com tactics trainer](https://www.chess.com/member/manuel_i_muro_sabater) while I haven't study theory and [my FIDE rating is 1637](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/32050208) ([I reached 1930 in rapids](http://echecs.asso.fr/Resultats.aspx?URL=Tournois/Id/30414/30414&Action=Ls) a year in France).

I want to study with a coach and there is one at my club who knows a lot of openings and endgames theory but is rated only 2000. Is his rating a limitation to teach me? I guess I need lessons not only in openings and endgames but in middlegame play. Should I search for a better trainer out of my club or it is enough that this coach train me?

Comment: You say the guy at your club "knows a lot of openings and endgames theory" but you want them to "teach middlegame play propertly"; isn't it a bit illogical?

Comment: @sleepy he is the only coach available at my club, then asking if I need to search outside

Comment: Magnus Carlsen has been coached by players over 200+ lower rated than him.

Comment: Studying chess is not into my priorities. I like to play 90+30 games from time to time to share my mistakes with my friends in this awesome forum. i have a premium account in chess.com to watch some videos, but think i am too much old to become FM. The funniest new of last weeks is Anatoly crunching Karjhaking lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is his rating a limitation to teach me?

No.

As I say in [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/23481/in-terms-of-rating-points-how-much-stronger-should-a-coach-be-than-their-studen/23483#23483), "you are too fixated on rating". High rating does not guarantee coaching ability. Low rating does not preclude coaching ability.

Today the guy in our club who does the most coaching is rated about 1900. 50 years ago, the first time we played for the same club, he was rated about 2150. He has coached a surprisingly large number of the players in our region who are now rated 2100-2300, although they moved on to better high level coaches before they got to those levels.

It is always interesting to watch him play one of his former students. Is the student going to give him a draw for old time's sake? Or crush him? If they give him a draw then afterwards the coach in him will tell them why they shouldn't do that while also saying "Thank you!"

> I need lessons not only in openings and endgames but in middlegame play. Should I search for a better trainer out of my club or it is enough that this coach train me?

We don't know the trainer so we haven't a clue. Probably the best approach for you is to have a trial lesson and see what you think. Did you learn anything? Was it worth it?

Taking a trainer is not like getting married. If you find it is not helping you then you can just stop and walk away.