# What does FIDE rating 1800 entail?

Tags: learning, fide, rating, tournament, tactics

I have a classical rating of around 2000 on Lichess. I’m aware that FIDE Classical time control is much longer than Lichess classical, so I just made it as some kind of reference point.

I’m mainly working on Soviet Chess Primer, Yusupov 1, and a tactics/endgames book that I carry with me.

There seem to be three main concepts that people advise intermediate players to focus on: Tactics, calculation/endgames, and positional concepts. Many say that the first two would produce most value for time put into.

So I think my question would be that what kinds or levels of tactics and calculation skills would someone of FIDE rating 1800 have? What differentiates someone of FIDE rating 2000 from 1800?

Comment: See also https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35137/precise-skills-connected-with-rating-value (and no, I haven't re-found the quote)

Answer (score 1):

As I have said before, learning chess is not like a factory. There is no checklist to complete to get a FIDE 1800 rating. However, a lichess.com rating of around 2000 generally does mean that you are in the 1800 range. But you are correct that tactics, calculation, endgames, and positional understanding are important. However they are also all related. Treating them as separate and focusing ont hem only separetly is not useful. What I would suggest is focusing on what you do wrong in games that you lose, which is true of any rating. Most of chess is learning from your mistakes.